# Equivalence of the union-closed sets conjecture that is locally weaker of any use?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, lattice-theory, conjectures

Let $F$ be a union-closed family. We call $F$ minimal if for every $x\in \cup(F)$ we find $S\in F$ such that $S\backslash \{x\} \in F$. It is sufficient to proof the union-closed sets conjecture for minimal families as explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3566870/improvement-on-the-concept-of-separating-families-for-the-union-closed-sets-conj). In the following we will always assume $F$ to be minimal.

Given $X\subsetneq \cup (F)$ and $S\in F$ let $S_X$ be the maximal element in $F$ with $S_X \subseteq S\cup X$. We now define $F\backslash X:= \{S\backslash X \mid S\in F\}$, $F_X^{\wedge}:=\{S_X \mid S\in F \}$, $F_X^{\vee}:=F\backslash F_X^{\wedge}$ and $(F_X^{\vee})_x := \{ S\in F_X^{\vee} \mid x\in S\}$ for $x\in X^{c}$ (complement in $\cup(F)$). One can make the following two observations:

**(1)** We have $|F\backslash X| = |F|-|F_X^{\vee}|$ and  $|(F\backslash X)_x| = |F_x| - |(F_X^{\vee})_x|$.

By that we will proof that the union-closed sets conjecture is equivalent to the following statement. For all union-closed families $F$ we find $X\subsetneq F$ such that for all $x\in X^{c}$ we have $|(F_X^{\vee})_x| \geq \frac{|F_X^{\vee}|}{2}$.

***Proof.*** $"\Rightarrow":$ Let $F$ be a union-closed family that satisfies the union-closed sets conjecture for the element $x\in \cup(F)$. By **(1)** it follows that $|F_{\{x\}^c}^{\vee}| = |F|-2$ and $|(F_{\{x\}^c}^{\vee})_x| = |F_x|-1$. We thus have $|(F_{\{x\}^c}^{\vee})_x| = |F_x|-1 \geq \frac{|F|-2}{2} = \frac{|F_{\{x\}^c}^{\vee}|}{2}$.

$"\Leftarrow":$ Since $F$ is minimal we have $|F\backslash X| < |F|$ so we can inductively assume that $F\backslash X$ satisfies the union-closed set conjecture for say $x\in X^{c}$. By **(1)** it follows that $|F_x|-|(F_X^{\vee})_x|=|(F\backslash X)_x | \geq \frac{|F\backslash X|}{2} = \frac{|F|-|F_X^{\vee}|}{2}$ but we also have $|(F_X^{\vee})_x| \geq \frac{|F_X^{\vee}|}{2}$ and thus $|F_x| \geq \frac{|F|}{2}$.

Since the proof for $"\Leftarrow"$ used induction it would not work if we fix a family $F$ however the proof for $"\Rightarrow"$ would. So in a sense the newly introduced statement is weaker locally and thus (maybe?) easier to proof. Could it be of any use in proving the union-closed sets conjecture?

Comment: It does not follow that the empty set is in F. Take F to be all subsets of the union having at least one element less than the union. The empty set is in F in the case that union is a singleton, and not for any larger set.  Gerhard "Is Not Following The Link" Paseman, 2020.03.02.

Comment: Thanks for the correction.